# DocuSign Service Integration User Consent not asking for permission or redirecting

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on developing a DocuSign integration with the DocuSign Sandbox.  I have an API key created with a redirect_uri of "https://www.google.com" specified for the api key, and an RSA keypair generated.  My app creates the url for user consent which ends up looking something like:

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=MyId&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com

I redirect to that Url and get the DocuSign login screen.  I login and it takes me to https://appdemo.docusign.com/home.  There is no ask for permission and no redirect to the redirect_uri.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It seems it never redirected to the [URL](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=MyId&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com) which you mentioned, can you manually hit your URL and see if you getting the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

As Amit suggests, to debug the problem have your code print out the url you are redirecting the user to. Then paste it into a browser to see what happens.

Ensure that, for example, MyID is being properly substituted.

Check that your client_id (Integration Key) is setup properly in DocuSign.

See my [video](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-docusign-application-authentication/) for more info.